# Set the UiSlider interval to 0.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uislider

I have a `UISlider` with `minimumValue 0` and `maximumValue`. I want to make an `interval` of `0.5` and display it in a `label` (it's working).

How can I set the interval of my `slider`? I tried solution to round the value... but I failed.

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
float RoundValue(UISlider * slider) {
  return roundf(slider.value * 2.0) * 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you !! Can you explain me this code? I don't understand the operation 2.0

Comment: `roundf(float)` rounds to the nearest whole. to get halves in the domain, multiply by 2.0, round to nearest int, then scale it back to the original range by multiplying by 0.5 (that is, the reciprocal of the formerly scaled amount).

Comment: Thanks bro.. it helped.

Answer (score 0):

when i do something like that i take an approach like the following:

```
 #define kSTEPFRACTION .5

 SliderMin = 0
 sliderMax = 20
```

and get the value withs something like that

```
 value = slider.value*kSTEPFRACTION;
```

this will give you values between 0 and 10 in steps of 0.5

sebastian